# Формула массива

Tags: массивы, функции, таблицы, формулы

Пожалуйста помогите) Не могу решить задачу с arrayformula.
Решил проблему с обычной формулой, но при вставке новых строк формула не копируется. Прошу решить проблему с функцией "формула массива"(((
Даты расположены в хронологическом порядке, но разделены несколькими строками. Задача: сформировать сплошную колонку дат, т.к. позже я буду сортировать данные в колонке справа от даты исходя из даты.
[image: Даты]
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

=Arrayformula(IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(A1:A)));A1:A;MAX(A$1:A1)))
=Arrayformula(IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(A1:A)));A1:A;MAX(A1:A)))
Не дало желаемого результата. Пустые строки заполнены первой или максимальной датой в массиве.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="";MAX(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW(A1:A)))&" "&A1&" "&ROW(A1:A);A1:A)) Не дало желаемого результата.
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Задача: сформировать из столбца A сплошную колонку дат, не прерывающихся на пустые строки. Образец в соседних столбцах B и C, но такого результата необходимо добиться функцией arrayformula.

Answer (score 0):

ARRAYFORMULA в данном случае мне не помогла, хотя допускаю, что кто-то предложит решение с нею. Предлагаю иной путь - на основе функции [REDUCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?sjid=2593339879848899895-EU).

```
=REDUCE(A2, A3:A50, LAMBDA(acc, v, VSTACK(acc, IF(v="", INDEX(acc, ROWS(acc)), v))))
```

Исходный диапазон я ограничил 50-м рядом, хотя это не принципиально (можно поставить A3:A, если нужно заполнить колонку на всю длину). Пробелы исходного диапазона будут заполнены ближайшими сверху значениями.